# please help me with this regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i use a slideshow jquery plugin
which automatically create a thumbnails path from my original image path
as
follows

```
replace: [/(\.[^\.]+)$/, 't$1'],
```

whenever i have a `blablablabla.jpg`

it knows that the thumb path is the same path with t suffix `blablablablat.jpg`

but i want to change this to `/thumb/blablablabla.jpg`

how can i achieve this using regular expression as the example above

Comment: What is your programming language and environment please?

Comment: @Benoit jQuery is a javascript library, so I would guess the regex also needs to be javascript.

Comment: replace is a property in a js file and it repalaces characters using regular expression [/(\.[^\.]+)$/, 't$1'] and it add 't' to the end of file name before the 'jpg' extention ex: ************.jpg become ************t.jpg - - - i want a regular expression to modify the ************.jpg to become /thumb/************.jpg - - - any help please

Comment: Could you provide a link to the plugin's page you're using? That would allow us to see what it does exactly with the regex, and it might allow us to point out a different config option you should use that better suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
replace: [/^(.+)$/, '/thumb/$1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
replace: [/([^./]+)(\.[^\.]+)$/, '/thumb/$1$2'],
```

Comment: this make the '4.jpg' become '4/thumb/.jpg'  i want a regular expression to modify the *********.jpg to become /thumb/***********.jpg - - - any help please

Comment: Edited to take separately filename and extension

Answer (score 1):

If you have blablablabla.jpg as input, then you do not need regexp for it at all. Simply prefix it with concatenation.

Comment: i try [/(\.[^\.]+)$/, '/thumb/'+'$1'], - but the result was convert 4.jpg to 4/thumb/.jpg - -but i need thumb/4.jpg

Comment: This is why I said completely forget regex. This is such simple: "thumb/" + pictureURL